# MySQL select as variable to be used in a function defined in PHP

Tags: mysql, variables, select

I think this a pretty classical setting: Suppose I have a `table tab1`, with `columns c1, c2`. Then I want to `select c1, c2` as variable of a function `fun(a,b)` in another select:

```
SELECT fun(@a,@b) as r FROM (SELECT @a:=c1, @b:=c2 FROM tab1) AS tab ORDER BY r LIMIT 10;
```

The fun is pre-defined in PHP:

```
function fun($d, $t){
      $timenow = time();
      $perd = 45000;
      $di = (int)$d;
      $tf = (float)$t;
      if ($di === 0)
      {
        return 0;
      }else{
        return (Log($di)/Log(10)+($timenow-$tf)/$perd);
      }
    }
```

The problem is that the variable is not updated at all. I build a test environment in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ffd6, the `fun(@a,@b)` is replaced by `@a` for simplicity.

---

UPDATE

It seems that my original question canot properly describe my problem. And I updated it, thanks to @wajeeh, the solution could be:

1. translate my php function into MYSQL form (it is a litter hard for me)
2. Use php function, but return the mysql results as array. (In that case I need to write the odering function by hand! and then (maybe) need another SELECT of MYSQL?)

Comment: Why do you need this function and what would be wrong with just selecting those columns directly from `tab1` ?

Comment: `fun(@a,@b)` maybe very complicated, for example I need $3*Log(@a+1)/EXP(@b)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can do that:

```
Select IF(c1 = 0, 0, LOG(c1)/LOG(10)+(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-c2)/45000) as r From tab1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7c23c/1/0)

Thanks to @Matt

Comment: Is there any possibility to make the constant `45000` as a vaiable that passed in by PHP? e.g. `$T=45000`, in fact, I defined it as an `env` constant in Laravel 5.

Comment: if you define your query directly from `PHP`, of course you can do that. like: `$T=45000; $sql = "Select .... $T .... From tab1"` then you call the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the function directly like this:

```
Select func(c1, c2) as r From tab1;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7961/1/0)

Comment: Yes, but the function must be defined in MYSQL then? In my case, I defined the function in php, and in that case `fun(c1,c2)` will not work.

Comment: How you can call a function from `PHP` in `MySQL` ?!!

Comment: To do that , You must return the results to `PHP` then enumerate over them calling the function you just defined. @vanabel

Comment: Try the second answer @vanabel

Comment: Yeah, I see, but it seem quite complicated. Especially I want to use the `fun` as a rank function to the result (in mysql ORDER BY fun).

Comment: Why you do not define the function in MySQL instead ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function func($param1, $param2) {
    // your code
}

$query = "Select c1, c2 From tab";
$stmt = $link->prepare($query);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NAMED)) {
        func($row["c1"], $row["c2"]); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the PHP function does or how it works so this may not be a perfect translation to a MySQL function but hopefully you can use it as a starting point.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION FUN(d INT, t FLOAT)
RETURNS FLOAT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
BEGIN
    IF d = 0 THEN
        RETURN 0;
    ELSE
        RETURN LOG(d)/LOG(10)+(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-t)/45000;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I almost do the exactly the same translation, but then there is a problem (not you answer itself, but my original problem) How to initialize it in Laravel, please see [Use user defnied function of mysql in Laravel5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788635/use-user-defnied-function-of-mysql-in-laravel5) in case you're interested in.